# Retain font awesome icon on page reload

Tags: javascript

I'm using the following code to show and hide forums

It works

The status show / hide is retained when the page is reloaded

But the font awesome icon goes back to default

what do I have to change so that the font awesome icon is retained during reload

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (window.localStorage.getItem("#wpf-cat-6 .forum-wrap") != null) {
    var pb = window.localStorage.getItem("#wpf-cat-6 .forum-wrap");
    if (pb == "true") {
      $("#wpf-cat-6 .forum-wrap").hide(); 
    }
  }

  $("#wpf-cat-6 .wpforo-toggle").click(function() {     
    var v = $("#wpf-cat-6 .forum-wrap").is(":visible")
    $("#wpf-cat-6 .forum-wrap").slideToggle("slow");
    $("#wpf-cat-6 .wpforo-toggle i").toggleClass('fa-chevron-up fa-chevron-down'); 
    window.localStorage.setItem("#wpf-cat-6 .forum-wrap", v)
  });   
});
```

Thanks in advance

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v1sbmr62/)

Comment: do the same setItem setup for the image tag?

Comment: I've tested a lot of different codes but none of them work, so I'm asking for the correct code here

Comment: could you make a jsfiddle or a repl of this(repl would prob work bettr)? because without the "awesome image tag" i have 0 clue what im looking at

Comment: thank you for your help, i have add demo fiddle in the post above

Answer (score 0):

After trying out many code variants, I found a solution
I don't know if everything is correct, but it works ;-)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (window.localStorage.getItem("#wpf-cat-6 .forum-wrap") != null) {
    var pb = window.localStorage.getItem("#wpf-cat-6 .forum-wrap");
    if (pb == "true") {
      $("#wpf-cat-6 .forum-wrap").hide();  
    }
  }

  $("#wpf-cat-6 .wpforo-toggle").click(function() {
    var v = $("#wpf-cat-6 .forum-wrap").is(":visible")
    $("#wpf-cat-6 .forum-wrap").slideToggle("slow");
     $("#wpf-cat-6 .wpforo-toggle i").toggleClass('fa-chevron-up fa-chevron-down');  
    window.localStorage.setItem("#wpf-cat-6 .forum-wrap", v)
  });
    $(document).ready(function () {
    if (localStorage.getItem('#wpf-cat-6 .forum-wrap') === 'true') {
    $("#wpf-cat-6 .wpforo-toggle i").toggleClass('fa-chevron-down fa-chevron-up'); 
    }
});
});
```